# Convert SQL statement to EF using a where date = year

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have this SQL Statement:

```
select * from Bookings where YEAR(DateCreated) = YEAR(2014)
```

How to do it in LINQ or Entity Framework style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ctx.Bookings.Where(a => y.SomeDate.Year == 2014);
```

Use the year part of DateTime